# C# Thread Abort Occur 'Safe Handle been Closed'

Tags: c#, serial-port, thread-safety

I have three class, Main, UserSerial, Communication

In Main

```
Communication Comm;
Thread CoTH;
UserSerial Serial;

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CoTH = new Thread(() =>
    {
        commJob();
    });
    CoTH.Start();
}

private void commJob()
{
    Serial.Setting();
    Serial.Open();
    Comm = new Communication(Serial);
    Comm.StartConnection(); 
}
```

In Communication

```
UserSerial Serial;

public Communication(UserSerial Serial)
{
    this.Serial = Serial;
}

public void Read()
{
    lock(Serial.Synchronous)
    {
        while(condition...)
        {
            Serial.Receive();
            // .... 
        }
    }   
}
```

And UserSerial is not my code, so I don't know detail..

Anyway, When I want serial communication force terminate, I Use Thread.Abort() in Main.

```
private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Serial != null)
            Serial.Close();
        if (CoTH != null)
            CoTH.Abort();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

But sometimes it occur 'Safe Handle been Closed', so program is abnormal termination.

How Can I communication force terminate without 'Safe Handle been Closed'?

Comment: `Thread.Abort` leaves things in undefined state... Do you really care if one of those is terminating your app?

Comment: I thought that Thread.Abort () was the cause because an error occurred when click btnstop.

Comment: Is `Safe Handle been Closed` an exception? Does it shows when your program crashed?

Comment: It seems you should stop `CoTH` first and then `Serial`. Or you will brutally terminate `CoTH` since it's using `Serial`. Imagine you terminate the socket while others keep calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should stop `CoTH` first and then `Serial`. Or you will brutally terminate `CoTH` since it's using `Serial` while not knowing it has been disposed.

In your class `Communication`. It's keep calling Serial.Receive().

```
public void Read()
{
    lock(Serial.Synchronous)
    {
        while(condition...)
        {
            Serial.Receive();
            // .... 
        }
    }   
}
```

However your `Stop` method is disposing resource `Serial` before closing the communication logic `CoTH`.

```
    if (Serial != null)
        Serial.Close();
    if (CoTH != null)
        CoTH.Abort();
```

You close Serial first. What if `Communication.Read()` wants to call `Serial.Receive()` after you closed it?

My suggestion:
Let Communication handle the resource, or a supervisor take care of their construction and destruction.